# Which indefinite number is most common in AmE?

Tags: american-english, numbers, common-word

**Which indefinite number having the suffix '-illion' is the most common one in American English in *colloquial speech*?**

I don't see how I could possibly arrive at the answer using the Internet. The best I can do as a competent speaker of American English is guess: 'gazillion'.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zillion%2Cbazillion%2Cgazillion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Czillion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbazillion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgazillion%3B%2Cc0

Comment: There are oodles of these words; not sure why you think the ones ending in -illion are special.  You could try a few or a plethora at Google  Ngrams https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Zillion%2Cgazillion%2Cbazillion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CZillion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgazillion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbazillion%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Actually, it's possible that people use *'million'* and *'billion'* to mean an indefinitely large number more often than to mean just 10^6 or 10^9.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is likely to be of use only to people feeling the need to collect trivia.

Comment: *Squillions* is the one I'm more inclined to use, or *his salary was a "telephone number"*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it is not a question about trivia to me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth are questions about trivia of English (which this question is not about) not allowed here? Please, post a link to this EL&U rule. If there is no such rule, you are just being judgmental, plain and simple.

Comment: The accepted answer in the Meta thread titled [Acceptability of trivia questions](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6535/acceptability-of-trivia-questions) gives the cogent reason 'I don't think trivia questions [example cited] are useful for users of this site.' The question here is certainly closeable for of lack of research shown (corpus data as provided in answers below is surely general reference on a site aimed at 'linguists and serious English language enthusiasts'). And, as JEL points out, such corpus data, though the best one can come up with, is rarely uncontestable.

Comment: On metaELU, unlike ELU, acceptance of an answer denotes agreement, not necessarily usefulness, and certainly not canonical 'correctness'. The quantity of upvotes on the other response to [Acceptability of trivia questions](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6535/acceptability-of-trivia-questions), which expresses a different viewpoint (to paraphrase, existing close reasons should suffice), suggests some disagreement exists. **Either way**, your question is *not trivial* but useful to writers and other professionals, and the answers show the resources are not "standard reference".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily answered by asking the corpus of American English Google digitized.

[The answer is zillion.](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/?c=us&q=50430123) Everything above is either a real number or not a number at all.

[image]

Comment: @JEL you're right, I added a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

The [SOAP Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/soap/), which contains the nearest approximation to colloquial American English of corpora I'm acquainted with, provides something of an answer:

[image: illion]

Discounting 'million' and 'billion' as not to the point, it looks as if 'zillion' is the clear winner. The picture might change if an -s is in play.

Comment: I guess the two corpora agree then. :)

Comment: @Helmar, oh, I hadn't followed your link. Good show. Not so rare an agreement then.